# Remote Upload Amazon S3

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have made an script to upload remote files by link to amazon s3 but does not work. I have no idea what's wrong. Below is all the code done and I'm using the Amazon SDK in its latest version:

config.php

```
<?php

return [
    's3' => [
        'key' => 'mykey',
        'secret' => 'mykey',
        'bucket' => 'mybucket',
        'region' => 'us-west-2',
        'version' => 'latest'
    ]
]

?>
```

start.php

```
<?php
use Aws\S3\S3Client;
require 'aws/aws-autoloader.php';

$config = require('config.php');

//S3

$s3 = S3Client::factory([
    'key' => $config['s3']['key'],
    'secret' => $config['s3']['secret'],
    'region' => $config['s3']['region'],
    'version' => $config['s3']['version']

]);
?>
```

upload.php

```
<?php

use Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception;
require 'start.php';

error_reporting(0);
$get_url = $_POST["url"];
$url = trim($get_url);
if($url)
{
    $file = fopen($url,"rb");
    $directory = "animes";
    $valid_exts = array("php","jpeg","gif","png","doc","docx","jpg","html","asp","xml","JPEG","bmp"); 
    $ext = end(explode(".",strtolower(basename($url))));
    if(in_array($ext,$valid_exts))
    {
        $rand = rand(1000,9999);
        $filename = "$rand.$ext";
        $newfile = fopen($directory . $filename, "wb");
        try{
            $s3->putObject([
                'Bucket' => $config['s3']['bucket'],
                'Key' => "{$directory}/{$filename}",
                'ACL' => 'public-read'
        ]);


    } catch(S3Exception $e){
        die("Error.");
    }
        if($newfile)
        {
            while(!feof($file))
            {
                fwrite($newfile,fread($file,1024 * 8),1024 * 8);
            }
            echo 'File uploaded successfully';
            echo '**$$**'.$filename;
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'File does not exists';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'Invalid URL';
    }
}
else
{
    echo 'Please enter the URL';
}
?>
```

and index.php

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>PHP File Upload From URL</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#1").hide();
        });
        function uploadfile(){
            $("#1").show();
            $("#disp").html("");
            var url = encodeURIComponent($("#url").val());
            $.ajax({
                url: "upload.php",
                data: "url=" +url,
                type: 'post',
                success: function(data)
                {
                    var findsucc = data.indexOf("successfully");
                    out=data.split('**$$**');
                    if(findsucc!=-1)
                    {
                        $("#disp").css({"color": "green"});
                        $("#disp").html(out[0]);
                        $("#link").html("<a href='./upload/"+out[1]+"'>Click here</a> to view");
                        $("#1").hide();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $("#1").hide();
                        $("#disp").css({"color": "red"});
                        $("#disp").html(data);
                        $("#url").val("");
                    }
                }
            });

        }
        </script>
    </head>
<body>
<div align='center' style='padding-top: 40px;color: #4e4e4e;'><h1>PHP File Upload From URL</h1></div>
<div align='center' style='padding-top: 30px;'>
Enter Remote URL: <input type="text" name="url" id='url' size="35"> <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="submit" style='cursor: pointer;' onclick='uploadfile()'>&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src='ajax-loader.gif' id='1'>&nbsp;&nbsp;<br /><br /><div align='center'><span id='disp'></span></div><br>
<div id='link'></div><br />
<div style=" padding-left: 20px;font-size: 10px;color: #dadada;" id="dumdiv">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Douglas, did you solve it yet? If so can you share that?

Comment: Still unresolved, but when you're working I can share.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to debug php is to run it via the command line version of php, this will show you your errors in the terminal instead of digging through webserver logs which may or may not give you any details.

Comment: How to do this? I'm using easyphp on Windows

Comment: ah, I'm unsure sorry. This is aimed at the unix command line environment. A quick google shows that something called XDebug exists for easyphp which lets you debug your code?